# Can I use a Spellheart on a shield or shield boss?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

Can I have a Spellheart on a shield? My weapon and armor already have Talismans, and I would like to have a Spellheart too.

I think it should work on a Shield Spike, as it is a weapon.
Is it a problem that I am not proficient with martial weapons?

Comment: I think the "Is it a problem that I am not proficient with martial weapons" probably merits its own question. "Can I use a talisman I've attached to a weapon I'm not proficient with" is a fairly different question than "Can I uses a Spellheart on a shield?"

Comment: Agreed, training has no impact on this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem not. All of the existing Spellhearts must be affixed to armor or weapon. You could attach a Spellheart to a shield boss or shield spike, as those are weapons, but not the shield itself.

Alternatively, if your goal is simply to have three usable Talismans (perhaps including a Spellheart), you could forgo a shield entirely and have two weapons with attached Talismans.

Comment: This is what I meant, a 3rd Talisman. If it is just indirectly on the shield, is not a problem for me

Comment: I hesitate to say it's your solution, since their could be esoteric mechanical differences between having the talisman attached to a shield, and having it attached to a shield weapon attachment. I mean, if all you wanted was to carry a third talisman, you could simply apply one to another weapon, and walk around with two weapons rather than weapon and shield.

Comment: For that matter, you could also just apply one on a handwraps of mighty blows, and use whatever weapons you want.